# AspxDocumentViewer XtraReport and empty data

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

I'm using XtraReport and AspxDocumentViewer. I wrote those codes to show. But I'm  always taking some problem; empty data.

How to fix this? I can't see what's wrong.

By the way "dsMast", it's dataset and there are ten rows. But still the report is empty.

```
string fpth = Server.MapPath(".");
fpth = fpth + "\\report\\rprFtrLst22222.repx";
XtraReport report = XtraReport.FromFile(fpth, true);
report.DataSource = dsMast;
report.LoadLayout(fpth);
report.CreateDocument();
string reportName = (string)"report";
ASPxDocumentViewer1.Report = report;
ASPxDocumentViewer1.DataBind();
Session["ReportName"] = reportName;
```

[image]

Comment: what happens when you debug the code..? do you see any data if you were to enter in to the quick watch the following 
`dsMast.Tables[0]` try settng the datasource to that and see if it works or see if the dataset or datatable has a LoadFromFile method and pass the report to the dataset.Tables[0].LoadFrom ...etc

Comment: I changed datasource, there are ten rows. But the problem is same.

Comment: go here and look at their documentation http://devexpress21.rssing.com/chan-15044660/all_p68.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem.
First of all, I added some code for page_load

```
        if (Session["report2"] != null)
        {
            ASPxDocumentViewer1.Report = Session["report2"] as XtraReport;
        }
```

And then I used thoso codes.

```
        report.DataSource = dsMast;
        report.LoadLayout(fpth);
        report.CreateDocument();
        ASPxDocumentViewer1.Report = report;
        ASPxDocumentViewer1.DataBind();
        Session["report2"] = report;
```